# Button on scrollView lost action event

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uibutton

How can I get action event on this button ?

```
self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];

UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
backButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 32);
backButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = YES;
[backButton setImage:backButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[_scrollView addSubview:backButton];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is good. implement this function

```
- (void)backButtonAction:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"backButton pressed");
}
```

if it not called so check userInteractionEnabled for scroolView and set to YES

```
_scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```